# Inequality with operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Hi I have A and B two bounded operators, I used the inequality
$$\||A|-|B|\|\leq\|A-B\|$$ 
where, $|A|=(A^*A)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $A^*$ the adjoint. But my professor said this is not necessarily true, I'm trying and I can't find a counterexample to see that. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Test it yourself, with $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&1},\ B=\pmatrix{1&2\\ 0&2}$ and the operator norm. The LHS of your inequality is about $1.44$, but the RHS is $\sqrt{2}$.